# Prove correctness of the following algorithm for computing Fibonacci numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science

I am a student studying for my BS in Computer Science. We recently got asked this question in on of my class and with no book to reference I am going to ask it here for a little help. I know I will have to use induction but I don't really understand how

```
Input: a, a natural number
Output: F_a, the ath Fibonacci number
Let i=1
While i<=a do
  if i=1 or i=2, then Fib(i)<-1
  else Fib(i)<-Fib(i-1)+ Fib(i-2)
  i <- i+1
end
Print Fib(a)
```

Comment: Tell whoever wrote this code that using "a" as an arbitrary natural number is very odd and the middle of the alphabet is much more preferable. Indeed, they say end of the alphabet for non-discrete variables (x, y, z; t, u, v), beginning of the alphabet for real constants (a, b, c) and middle of the alphabet to signify an arbitrary natural number (l, m, n, k)

Comment: Should the sixth line not have `Fib(i)` in place of `Fib(1)`? In any case, how have you defined the Fibonacci numbers? And what kind of proof are you looking for? What similar problems have you done? And what exactly is your question? (There's not a single question mark here!)

Comment: @MiloBrandt I think it's implicit here that Fib is an indexed array, and we are using dynamic programming to build "from the bottom up" the fibonacci numbers up to $a$ in order to find the $a$th fibonacci number.

Comment: I don't understand what your question is: You've just posted a chunk of pseudocode.

Comment: There is no question here (notice there is no ?).  What do you need help with?  What is your question?

Comment: @Soke, `a` is a fine variable name. I use it often, even not in a program/pseudocode setting.

Comment: @MiloBrandt, bug fixed.

Comment: I think you are more likely to run into coding errors than mathematical errors.

Answer (score 4):

I think you might be overthinking the problem. The induction is pretty simple; let's go through the steps:

**Base case:** The algorithm correctly puts Fib(1) = 1, Fib(2) = 1.

**(Strong) Inductive step:** Suppose the algorithm correctly calculates the values for Fibonacci numbers up to $k$.

Then, it puts Fib(k+1) = Fib(k) + Fib(k-1), so the value of Fib(k+1) is correctly calculated too.

Answer (score 0):

```
Input: a, a natural number
Output: F_a, the a'th Fibonacci number

1 Let i = 1
2
3 While i <= a do
4    
5  if i = 1 or i = 2 then Fib[i] <- 1
6
7  else Fib[i] <- Fib[i - 1] + Fib[i - 2]
8
9  i <- i + 1
10
11 end
12
13 Print Fib[a]
```

First determine what you are trying to prove:

> At line 12, $\operatorname{Fib}[a] = F_a$

Now consider some assumptions you will need to prove it:
$$F_a = F_{a - 1} + F_{a - 2}$$
$$F_1 = 1$$
$$F_2 = 1$$

To prove this kind of statement, you need to establish what is called a *loop invariant*.  This is a statement for which, if it is true at the start of 1 pass of the loop (line 4), then it is true at the end of that pass of the loop (line 10).  Here your primary loop invariant is:

$$\forall j ~:~ 1 \le j < i \implies \operatorname{Fib}[j] = F_j \tag{L}$$

After using the definition of the fibonacci sequence to prove that **(L)** is a loop invariant, if you can prove that **(L)** holds at line 2 (before the loop) then it must hold at line 12 (after the loop).

Furthermore, the loop condition at line 3 implies that at line 12 $\lnot (i \le a)$.

So you are left with two statements being true at line 12:

$$\begin{cases}
\forall j ~:~ 1 \le j < i \implies \operatorname{Fib}[j] = F_j \\
i > a
\end{cases}$$

Those two together are enough to establish that at line 12, $\operatorname{Fib}[a] = F_a$.

To prove that the program terminates, you need to establish a decreasing ordinal during the loop.  So to establish halting you need to prove that $a - i + 1$ is always positive and decreasing during the loop.

Aside, this is also why most people don't bother attempting to prove things about procedural programs, but rather prefer functional programs.